# Passing Relative Paths to Powershell shell.application Namespace

Tags: powershell, zip

I'm attempting to get the function from this page:
https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-extract-zip-files-using-powershell/ working using relative parameters.

So I have this function:

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
    Write-Host "Unzipping $file to $destination" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
    }
}
```

And I attempt to call it like so:

```
$zipPath = Resolve-Path ".\myZip.zip"
$destinationPath = Resolve-Path ".\"
Expand-ZIPFile -File $zipPath -Destination $destinationPath
```

Output wise I see:

```
Unzipping D:\test\myZip.zip to D:\test
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\test\Unzip.ps1:14 char:22
+     foreach($item in $zip.items())
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Which I'm assuming is because the `namespace` isn't being interpretted correctly because if I call:

```
Expand-ZIPFile -File "D:\test\myZip.zip" -Destination "D:\test"
```

This works fine, and I see:

```
Unzipping D:\test\myZip.zip to D:\test
```

in the console as well.

How can I pass in the 'resolved' strings, as I can't see what's missing here.

I have also tried wrapping the resolved strings in `"` to see if that made a difference (`$zipPath = '"' + $zipPath + '"'`) but to no avail.

Comment: try: $zipPath = (Resolve-Path ".\myZip.zip").Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is coming from `Resolve-Path`. It is returning an object with a path property as supposed to a straight string. I would have thought that the console output for your `write-host` line would look weird as an indicator but it looks like it has a nice `ToString()` overload.

You need to expand that property out.

```
$zipPath = (Resolve-Path ".\myZip.zip").Path
$destinationPath = (Resolve-Path ".\").Path
Expand-ZIPFile -File $zipPath -Destination $destinationPath
```

You can see the need for this when you output `Resolve-Path` to standard out.

```
resolve-path .\sql.txt

Path                     
----                     
C:\Users\myusername\sql.txt
```

Comment: Ahhh I was confused by the object being returned but looking the same, thank you!